# Определить способ образования

Tags: словообразование

Определить способ словообразования - *воздействие*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

СУФФИКСАЛЬНЫЙ.

**воздейств**овать -> воздейств-**иj**-е

Comment: Странно, ведь у слова "воздействовать" основа неопределенной формы - "воздействова-", значит, к этой основе должен при суффиксальном способе присоединиться суффикс. Но какой суффикс? -Иj- Как-то не сходится. По-моему, здесь все просто: к слову "действие" прибавилась приставка "воз-"

Comment: наверное, усечение основы и прибавления суффикса. способ- суффиксальный

Comment: Там еще и приставка есть - как в словах воздвигнуть, возмутиться, воспрять, восторг, возмущение.

Answer (score 0):

Слава прав, это суффиксальный способ. Вы путаете состав слова и словообразовательный способ. В данном случае слово ''воздействие'' образовалось от воздействовать при помощи суффикса-иj.

Смотрим у Тихонова: воз/де́й/ств/и/е [й/э]